# The effect of different mediums on the molecular orbital energies

Tags: reference-request, molecular-interactions, solvation, energy

I want to study the effect of different mediums, gas and various solvents, on the energy of the 10th highest molecular orbital of multiple quinones, which I obtained by a Gaussian software calculation. I already have these energies in each case, but I do not know how to compare them. I was thinking about using a python program to sort them for every molecular orbital. But even if I will do so, I do not know how to analyze the result afterward.

**Can you suggest a way to study the effect of solvation on the molecular orbital energies of these systems? Can you recommend a book or an article about this?**

Comment: I'm not sure I understand why you'd want to focus on the 10th orbital, since different molecules will have different numbers of orbitals. Usually you'd focus on the HOMO and/or LUMO. But usually, I'd recommend using `cclib` to parse output files. You can get `moenergies` (in eV).

Comment: As far as solvation, usually people would be interested in shifts going to solvents of increasing polarity or dielectric constant.

Comment: @GeoffHutchison Thank you very much for your answer, it is very helpful.

Comment: @sarra6 Did Geoff's comments help you solve your problem? Do you have any update since December?

Comment: @NikeDattani No, not really, because I am not familiar with the cclib library and I am trying to learn how to use it.

Comment: @sarra6 How about now? Have you become familiar with cclib? You can ask questions here about cclib if you have any!